# Angular 8 - how to trigger animation with different values on Desktop and Mobile?

Tags: angular, animation

I'm finishing my webApp and making it responsive.
I encountered one last issue I cannot seem to solve!

I've got an animation, for a popover-like element, that slides from `Left` to `Right` on desktop.

On mobile, there is not enough space, so I'll make that element open below the Input field, not on the side, so I need an animation that slides from `Bottom` to `Top` .

This is the code for default animation I use for Desktop screens:

```
animations: [
    trigger("slideInOut", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ transform: "translateX(60%)", opacity: 0 }),
        animate(
          "300ms ease-in",
          style({ transform: "translateX(0%)", opacity: 1 })
        ),
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        animate(
          "300ms ease-in",
          style({ transform: "translateX(60%)", opacity: 0 })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]
```

and the only thing I want to change are the 3 values for `transform`

For mobile I would need:

```
translateY(60%)
translateY(0%)
translateY(60%)
```

so basically just swap the X axis with the Y!

How can I achieve this? 
If not possible to change these values, even disabling the animation for mobile would work!

I thought of a solution but is dirty, much dirty!
Basically I would create a copy of my "popover-like DIV", then on both of them, slap a class, for example:

```
.mobile

.desktop
```

Then, based on Media Queries, I would display one or the other, and finally on each one of them, I would attach a different animation trigger, and I would declare both triggers in my component, one for the Y axis and one for the X axis.
This should work but I dont like it at all!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use an Angular animation here? A simple thing like this could be done in pure css with Angular only setting some dynamic classes.

Comment: no of course there is not, I m not animation expert, so I went the easy way with what I knew in Angular! what would be the equivalent of this animation in css?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used a mobile query to choose the div's class and then, in the animation query, wrote the different animations based on classes. By this way I'm able to use very indipendent animations, without passing parameters.

mycomponent.html

```
<div class="dp-a" [@fadeOut]>
    <div class="d0" (click)="closePanel()"></div>
        <div [ngClass]="mobileQuery.matches? 'd1':'d1-desktop'"><!--HERE class query-->
```

mycomponent.ts

```
query('.d1', // mobile class
    animate('0.3s ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' })), 
    { optional: true }
),
query('.d1-desktop', // desktop class
    animate('0.2s ease-out', style({ transform: 'scale(1)' })), 
    { optional: true }
)
```

Important note: don't forget `{ optional: true }`. It is required with ternary operator in `[ngClass]`, because of the class selection.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue and managed to solve the problem. Not sure if this is the best solution but it works.

So in the component I listen the page width size. Don't forgot to call the listener from the constructor, otherwise will be triggered only when the screen is resized.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: '{{translateType}}(-100%)' }),
        animate('900ms ease-in', style({ transform: '{{translateType}}(0%)' })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [animate('700ms ease-in', style({ transform: '{{translateType}}(-100%)' }))]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class MyComponent {
  screenWidth: number;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.onResize();
  }

  getAnimationTransformValue(): string {
    return this.screenWidth <= 800 ? 'translateY' : 'translateX';
  }
}
```

And in your html template I used the following syntax to pass in the style transform value.

```
<div  [@slideInOut]="{ value: true, params: {translateType: getAnimationTransformValue() }}">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: that's a nice solution! At the end I went with creating the same DIV twice, creating 2 separate animations, one for the X and one for the Y transition, and finally use a CSS class to hide/show those DIVs depending if mobile or not..I might eventually change to your solution as it is much more cleaner